# Can KIF target UIWebView components?

Tags: ios, testing, uiwebview, kif-framework

Is it possible to target UIWebView components in KIF testing?

I've managed to get limited functionality by using `stepToTapScreenAtPoint` but there are major issues when the target content is "below the fold".

I've also had limited success using `stepToEnterText:kTestEmail intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Email"]` but although it can find the input field & start typing, the test fails after finishing typing.

So my question is does KIF support targeting webview-based steps? What's the correct way of testing this?

Thanks! (KIF results below)

```
Integration[29024:c07] PASS (0.01s): Tap screen at point "{50, 520}"
2012-11-06 14:49:58.493 Integration[29024:c07] FAIL (4.48s): Type the text "[redacted]" into the view with accessibility label "Email"
2012-11-06 14:49:58.494 Integration[29024:c07] FAILING ERROR: Error Domain=KIFTest Code=0 "Failed to actually enter text "[redacted]" in field; instead, it was "SIGN UP
Sign in

Email

Password

   Stay signed in
Can't access your account?
Coming soon: A new sign-in page! Try it now Learn more
© 2012 Google Privacy Policy Help"" UserInfo=0x14eda060 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to actually enter text "[redacted]" in field; instead, it was "SIGN UP
Sign in

Email

Password

   Stay signed in
Can't access your account?
Coming soon: A new sign-in page! Try it now Learn more
© 2012 Google Privacy Policy Help"}
2012-11-06 14:49:58.494 Integration[29024:c07] ---------------------------------------------------
2012-11-06 14:49:58.494 Integration[29024:c07] END OF SCENARIO (duration 11.15s)
2012-11-06 14:49:58.495 Integration[29024:c07]
```

Answer (score 2):

A year later and still nobody posts a solution so then I'll share that I had a similar issue that I just made a work around for by using the first responder instead of entering into the text field.

Here's a snippet from my code in my project.  Just make it work with yours.  Hope this helps somebody!

```
//Make sure the field is in view
[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToWaitForTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Username"]];

//This will pop the keyboard to screen
[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToTapViewWithAccessibilityLabe:@"Username"]];

[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToEnterTextIntoCurrentFirstResponder:@"testUser"]];
```